# c# same command for different textboxes

Tags: c#

I was wondering if I could do this, but but all in one function. As in if I could clear every all textboxes on the event "enter" without creating multiple functions.

```
 private void textBox4_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox4.Clear();
        }

        private void textBox3_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox3.Clear();
        }

        private void textBox5_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox5.Clear();
        }

        private void textBox2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox2.Clear();
        }

        private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Clear();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same method for all events: the textbox that triggers the event will be the `sender` parameter of the method. All you have to do is cast it to `TextBox` and call `Clear` on it:

```
private void textBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as TextBox).Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Build the method like this:

```
private void textBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as TextBox)?.Clear();
}
```

And then set it up like this:

```
public MyForm()
{
    //This is your form's constructor

    InitializeComponent();

    textBox1.Enter += textBox_Enter;
    textBox2.Enter += textBox_Enter;
    textBox3.Enter += textBox_Enter;
    textBox4.Enter += textBox_Enter;
    textBox5.Enter += textBox_Enter;
}
```

But for such a simple method, you haven't really gained anything. I'd also find it quite annoying to have a TextBox clear like that.

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to avoid creating extra methods at all by doing this:

```
foreach (var textBox in new [] { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5 })
{
    var tb = textBox;
    tb.Enter += (_s, _e) => tb.Clear();
}
```